# Is there a -meter for length measurement?

Tags: word-request

You know barometer, manometer, thermometer, voltmeter, which are all instruments for making measurements.

I'd like to know whether there's a *-meter* for length measurement. Like *distancemeter*, *lengthmeter* or maybe even *metermeter*.

I am aware that we have words like *folding rule*, *caliper gauge*, *micrometer gauge*  and *coordinate measurement machine*, but I'm specifically looking for a *-meter* kind of word for making a point in a Youtube video where I explain the word *meter* in general (and of course compare it to the standalone *meter* which is for the unit).

Comment: Don't forget that in British English, "meter" *always* means a measuring device, because the unit of length is spelled "metre". (Also, you've just reminded me that I need to read my gas and electricity meters!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device fitted to vehicles that displays distance traveled on the dashboard is called an [odometer](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/odometer).

This is also called a [mileometer](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mileometer) (or milometer) in British English, where miles are the standard measurement for speed and distance on roads.

A manual device for measuring distances, usually called a 'measuring wheel' or a 'surveyor's wheel', is also known as an '[hodometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodometer)'.

Comment: Thanks. Someone with a wiktionary account might want to add that in [-meter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-meter).

Comment: @ThomasWeller I don't think that is meant to be an exhaustive list. Also, I found you another word. We used to use 'hodometers' at school for measuring land in Geography class. Apparently, this is  also the original word for an odometer.

Comment: The wiktionary list is *definitely* neither exhaustive nor intended to be, but that said, odometer is a lot more common in usage than a lot of the other terms on that list, so I went ahead and added it.  Milometer and hodometer are derivatives of odometer, so I'd rather not clutter the list.